# Connect image files in two folders with python regular expression

Tags: files, regular-expression, python, images

I have two folders with the names images and labels like th following

The following code creates a function that links files in images folder with their corresponding files in labels by using _P suffix.

```
images
case_00004_imaging_127.tif 
case_00004_imaging_128.tif 
case_00004_imaging_1290.tif

labels
case_00004_imaging_127_P.tif 
case_00004_imaging_128_P.tif 
case_00004_imaging_129_P.tif
```

A function that connects images with their relative files

```
path_lbl = path/'labels'
path_img = path/'images'
get_y_fn = lambda x: path_lbl/f'{x.stem}_P{x.suffix}'
```

How can I modify the above function if I have files like the following

```
images

case_00004_imaging_127.tif 
case_00004_imaging_128.tif 
case_00004_imaging_1290.tif

labels 
case_00004_segmentation_127.tif 
case_00004_segmentation_128.tif 
case_00004_segmentation_1290.tif
```

Comment: what language is that supposed to be?  can you add its label to your question please?

Comment: bash. Thanks. I added.

Comment: this doesn't look like bash `get_y_fn = lambda x: path_lbl/f'{x.stem}_P{x.suffix}'`

Comment: you are right. it's a regular expression (REGEX).

Comment: with respect, no it's not.  It looks almost like python but the slash isn't properly escaped for concatenation.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I think it is regular expression in Python.